# C# Windows App how to get html source code form WebView

Tags: c#, windows

How to get html source code form WebView component in c#?

Comment: What platfrom are you talking about?

Comment: Windows 8 - 10, Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `InvokeScript` or `InvokeScriptAsync`methods. Do make sure the page is loaded first.

```
string html = await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
var text = html;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have no idea why before not work

Comment: Is there any method to check page loaded status?

Comment: The `loadCompleted` event should do the trick